# I can't click a link in a dynamic table cell in Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My project has one dynamic table. I need to go to a particular cell and click on an available link. I had reached a particular cell but am unable to click on the link which appears in the table cell.

```
@Test(priority = 1)
public void projectDelete() throws Exception {
    int rowCount = -1;
    int columnCount = 0;
    WebElement table = webdriver.findElement(By.id("projectList"));
    List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    for (WebElement row : allRows) {
        rowCount++;
        List<WebElement> rowCells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        for (WebElement cell : rowCells) {
            columnCount++;

            String projectName = cell.getText();

            if (projectName.equals("TEST1")) {
                System.out.println("Table Data" + cell.getText());
                System.out.println("Table Row " + rowCount);

                System.out.println("TEST PROJECT LINE FOUND ..... "
                        + rowCount);

                webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='projectList']/tbody/tr[rowCount]/td[5]")).click();
                webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='493']")).click();
            }
        }
        columnCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Table DataTEST1
Table Row 76
TEST PROJECT LINE FOUND ..... 76
FAILED: projectDelete
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='projectList']/tbody/tr[rowCount]/td[5]"}
Command duration or timeout: 20.06 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
```

Comment: please post the HTML code if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a single pass through your code, I found the following issue

Change the following

```
webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='projectList']/tbody/tr[rowCount]/td[5]")).click();
```

to

```
webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='projectList']/tbody/tr["+rowCount+"]/td[5]")).click();
```

On second thoughts, I have some suggestions on your code :-

1. Instead of finding the table as a whole, you can find the tbody since your data under test lies here.
2. I believe, you know in which column the project name. So you can avoid the loop for iterating through the List rowCells. Instead you can directly use rowCells.get(index) to get the exact column(index starts from 0. If your project name is in column 2, then index =1).
3. The same is applicable for the column which contains the link to click(). Use rowCell.get(index) to get the column and then click on it.

So your code can be modified as follows :-

```
@Test(priority = 1)
public void projectDelete() throws Exception {
    //find tbody
    WebElement table = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("/table[@id='projectList']/tbody"));

    //get all rows
    List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

    //iterate through the rows
    for (WebElement row : allRows) {
            //get the rowCells in each row
            List<WebElement> rowCells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

            //get the column which contains the project name and get text
            String projectName = rowCells.get(indexofColumnwhichhasProjectname).getText();

            //Compare if the project name equals TEST1
            if (projectName.equals("TEST1")) {
                System.out.println("Table Data : " + projectName);
                System.out.println("Table Row : " + rowCells.indexOf(projectName));

                //get the column containing the link and click on it.
                rowCells.get(4).click();

                //webdriver.findElement(By.id("493")).click();
                //Img is contained within the row containing the project Name
                //So, find the Img in the row and click
                row.findElements(By.cssSelector("img[alt='Delete Project']")).click();                }
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: close.  you are encapsulating `rowCount` in quotes when you shouldn't be.

Comment: lost answer is working fine ...  but line @ webdriver.findElement(By.id("493")).click(); id("493") is changing every time. how to control this?

Comment: <a href="#">
<img id="493" class="delete" width="16" height="16" title="Delete Project" alt="Delete Project" src="../media/internalnotforuse/images/icons/del.png"/>
</a>

Comment: then i suggest you to use xpath without taking id into consideration. Or you could use css Selector. img[alt='Delete Project'] (Assuming that the alt attribute is constant :))

Comment: rowCells.get(5).click();
     webdriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt='Delete Project']")).click(); 
   webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='deleteError_confirm']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/input[1]")).click();      it is working but deleting first row from the table instead of particular row from table.

Comment: is this element found within the row containing the Project Name. If yes, I have modified my answer. Please accept my answer if it works !! :)

Comment: row.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt='Delete Project']")).click(); is fine ....